# TLPhotoPicker dismissPhotoPicker Doesn't Add Video

Tags: swift, photo-picker

I am trying to fetch and append a video file from the gallery. I can select and append image files but when I try to fetch video files my withTLPHAssets ignores it and only shows images not videos. How should I fetch a video file without crashing?

I am using TLPhotoPicker pod.

Below I added dismissPhotoPicker

```
extension TLPhotoPickerManager: TLPhotosPickerViewControllerDelegate {

func dismissPhotoPicker(withTLPHAssets: [TLPHAsset]) {
    selectedTLPHAssets = withTLPHAssets
    didSelectTLPHAsset?(withTLPHAssets, videoUrl)
    if selectedTLPHAssets.contains(where: { $0.fullResolutionImage == nil && $0.type != .video }) {
        var assets = selectedTLPHAssets.filter {
            $0.fullResolutionImage != nil || $0.type == .video
        }
        // MARK: Bunu yazan kör oldu... elleme...
        if assets.count > 0 {
            for i in 0...assets.count - 1 {
                assets[i].selectedOrder = i + 1
            }
        }
        /// END ///
        Dialog.shared.showTopAlert(body: "newsfeed_post.share.getting.image.fail".localized)
        didSelectTLPHAsset?(assets, videoUrl)
    } else {
        didSelectTLPHAsset?(withTLPHAssets, videoUrl)
    }
}
```